# Image Scaling IE8

Tags: html, image, internet-explorer-8, css

I'm working on an html email template for a friend of mine. It's simple so I have everything inside a table as I figured it would be the fastest way to construct it. The issue I'm having is I need the table and the images inside it to scale with the browser and in both FF and Chrome it's working just fine. However, in IE8 I cannot get the max-width attribute to work. I need both the table and the images to have max-widths and it just isn't happening. I'm trying to set a max width of 720px to the table, but it won't scale unless I set it to 100%, which messes up the formatting.

As for the images, if I set their width's to 100% they will scale down just fine when the browser is adjusted, but at full screen they are entirely too big.

I have tried:

```
    table{width:inherit; max-width:720px; width:auto;}
    img{max-width:720px; width: 100%;}
```

And other variations of this. As I said, it's working in FF and Chrome.

Comment: if the table is the first element in your document after the opening body element? i'm confused because you said you used width:inherit. more on that when you respond, but offhand, set your max width to the body or html element, then 100% or auto on the table and img.

Answer (score 0):

IE adds "random" `hspace` and `vspace` to the images. Perhaps that causes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I would look for more articles online for email template fluid designs, one article at Smashing Magazine: [From Monitor to Mobile Optimizing Email Newsletters with CSS](http://mobile.smashingmagazine.com/2011/08/18/from-monitor-to-mobile-optimizing-email-newsletters-with-css/) is a great start.

Support for emails is shaky at best, it hasn't yet caught up with modern methods. without anymore code than you've provided I can't help much more than this at this time.

Update: Also check [Applying fluid layouts to HTML Email designs](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/post/3564/applying-fluid-layouts-to-html-email-design/), it has a min/max-width compatibility chart that may help.